# MySQL transaction behavior on INSERTS

Tags: mysql, transactions

I need to run a transaction to do "all or nothing" but I'm with some problems getting there.

In the example bellow the 3rd INSERT fails, but I get the first two inserted. The thing is that I need to do all or nothing. Or insert all or insert none.

How can I possibly do this in MySQL? I'm using InnoDB.

```
START TRANSACTION;
insert into t_orders (id_order, date_begin, date_end) values ('1', '2012-9-08', '2012-9-16');
insert into t_orders_items (id_order, id_order_item, id_item, item_quantity) values ('1', '1', '2', '1');
insert into t_orders_items (id_order, id_order_item, id_item, item_quantity) values ('1', '1', '3', '1');
COMMIT;
```

Some clues?

Best Regards,

Comment: What is the table type? MyISAM doesn't support transactions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [duplicate key error does not cancel/rollback mysql transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630400/duplicate-key-error-does-not-cancel-rollback-mysql-transaction)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your storage type. With an InnoDB table, this will work, but MyISAM doesn't support transactions and ignores the START TRANSACTION statement. Change the storage engine for your table to InnoDB. It is a (tiny) little slower, but a lot safer.

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, I'm using InnoDB

Comment: That's odd. No reason it shouldn't work then, unless errors in the execution aren't caught and you call commit anyway. I'd expect MySQL (and any database for that matter) to implicitly rollback the transaction if an error occurs, but MySQL has surprised me before, so you could validate if that is the case.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any detail about the data structure of these two table?
It looks like that there might be a primary key or unique in t_orders_items, and you are trying to insert a similar value which cause the transaction failed

Comment: if you mean to ask any question to original question poster than you should put that up as comment instead of an answer. Once you are sure of answer than you should put it up as answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's quiet simple, at the table t_orders_items: the id_order is a primary key and you have inserted the same value '1' two times ..
Good luck

Comment: The question is not why the insert fails, but why the transaction refuses to rollback.

Comment: you can't rollback a false transaction